# What is difference between provideTasks and resolveTask of vscode.TaskProvider?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The document from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider doesn't explain clearly what are the difference between them and why `resolveTask` has better performance than `provideTasks`. As when I compared the times both methods are called, I found that `resolveTask` get called more often (I use `vscode.tasks.fetchTasks` a lot in my extension https://github.com/ludenstian/automatask). For example, if I use `provideTasks` to read `tasks.json` and return list of tasks in `tasks.json`, would it be better than let `provideTasks` return [] and implements `resolveTask` for each task sent to it?